# Android : One Signal Push notification did not receive while the app is in use

Tags: android-studio, push-notification, onesignal

I am using **One Signal Push notification** in my app. When my app is in **closed** that mean when I am not using of my app, I **get push notification** from one signal that is sent from my testing team. But when I **am using an app**, I **did not get** it.

Your answer is more appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

In latest version (3.+@aar) you should use `inFocusDisplaying`:

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
  .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
  .init();
```

And you can set `None` and `InAppAlert` instead of `Notification`.

Answer (score 1):

By using this line,I can get the push notification though my app is in opened.

[Link to refer](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/android-sdk-api#NotificationOpenedHandler)

```
OneSignal.enableNotificationsWhenActive(true);
```

Comment: Link is Expired and not Works with latest Versions

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43471730/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.